# Designing a REST adaptor with ActiveRecord?

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns, activerecord, language-agnostic, dependency-injection

I am connecting to a REST service. It's QuickBlox, to be specific, but it should not matter other than that the REST API is defined like a SQL query (but notably minus the joins) and I can do CRUD on it.

QuickBlox provides iOS SDK, which gives me an interface to construct the REST query with a callback.

In my program I want objects like `User`, `UserResourceTable`, `Card`, for example. (It's not exactly like this as `User` resides in a special QuickBlox module, but for the sake of the question it's OK to ignore this.)

I have constructed something I think is similar to the ActiveRecord pattern (I hope). So in my `User` class I have CRUD methods, and `Card` class also. And these CRUD have callbacks (or rather, Objective-C blocks which are closures).

Originally I have "read" as class method (like a Java static method), since before calling `read` there is nothing about the object that's read so I thought I would provide a static factory method on the aforementioned classes.

`UserResourceTable` is not directly expose to whoever uses the `User` class. It's created when `User` is created and read when `User` is read.

Now this all went OK until I started to think about unit-testing. I end up deciding to do dependency injection (DI), then I want `UserResourceTable` to be injected into User. But it now seems difficult to do DI while `read` is a class method/static method and I now think I want `read` to be an instance method. (Especially there is no static variable in Objective-C and even if I can use static variable in the file to kind of use it I wouldn't know when to inject it. It just smell bad to me.)

Now read would be something like this (**pseudo code**):

```
User user = User(); // user just so we can call read()
User userFetched = user.read();
```

A few questions:

1. Is it a good idea to have read as an instance method?
2. Is ActiveRecord suitable for my situation? Perhaps a better model?
3. Right now the `User`, `UserResourceTable`, and `Card` all directly uses QuickBlox sdk (or rather, via a thin wrapper). And I intend to inject `UserResourceTable` into `User`. I also like to inject Quickblox's interface (or the thin wrapper) into `User`, `UserResourceTable`, and `Card`. I would have some factories to do this. Does that sound any good?

Comment: Giving it a quick glance, the user.read() may make more sense as a static method than a method call.  The top User user = User() is a little bogus because you really don't have a "user" yet.

Comment: @seand That was what I was thinking, but then it makes dependency injection pretty difficult if not impossible.